# No more _source if script_fields is used in elasticsearch query

Tags: field, elasticsearch

I am running a simple query like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "statuses": "active"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "test": {
      "script": "_source.name"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that once I introduce the `script_fields`, I no longer get `_source` in my results.

I have tried:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "_all"
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "statuses": "active"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "email": {
      "script": "_source.name"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "statuses": "active"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "email": {
      "script": "_source.name"
    }
  }
}
```

But they did not make any difference. Is there a way to get `_source` returned in addition to the `script_fields`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the `fields` array, make it load `_source`:

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "statuses": "active"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "email": {
      "script": "_source.name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know exactly _why_ this happens? Is it related to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20068 ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/a

curl -X POST localhost:9200/a/b/c -d '{"title" : "foo"}'

curl -X POST localhost:9200/a/_refresh

echo;

curl localhost:9200/a/_search?pretty -d '{
  "fields": [
    "_source"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "title_script": {
      "script": "_source.title"
    }
  }
}'
```

Output:

```
"hits" : {
  # ...
  "hits" : [ {
    # ...
    "_source" : {"title" : "foo"},
    "fields" : {
      "title_script" : "foo"
    }
  } ]
}
```