# How to use the native java client in order to restore the _source if a script field is used in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to use the native elasticsearch client in order to retrieve the source when script fields are used.

Here is a way to do it using JSON/http:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856215/536299

I have not been able to find a way to achieve this through the native java client.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there is a `setFetchSource(boolean fetch)` method available on `SearchRequestBuilder`.

See below:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client
                .prepareSearch(ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX)
                .setTypes(ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE)
                .setFetchSource(true)//Notice here
                .addScriptField("distance", distanceScript(queryForm))
                .addAggregation(aggregations(queryForm))
                .setQuery(filters(queryForm))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

This allows to fetch the source even when a script field is used.